# Running a servlet using URL

Tags: java, servlets

hi there ,
                 i have a url of a servlet . i want to invoke this servlet using this url in java application(Google app engine to rackespace server). is it possible or not.

```
 String url = "https://.......";
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)new URL(url).openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

YES You can access Servlet URL using java.

Comment: but it can not invoke servlet..whenever i try